# How do you find relative motion of two objects not travelling in a straight path?

Tags: kinematics, relative-motion

I understand relative motion linearly, but how about more complex motion, like travelling in a circle? Would you just find the objects velocities at some point using the formula $v=\omega r$ and then treat it as linear motion? What about oscillatory motion, or would that be the same as circular motion?

Comment: Have you learned about using vectors to describe motion?

Comment: Usually I use velocity vectors and what not to describe motions (like projectile motion).

Answer (score 2):

A change of momentum with constant mass requires external force:
$$ \frac {\partial \vec P}{\partial t} = \vec F$$ Imagine holding a ball attached to a rope. If you spin the ball via the rope, the rope is producing the external force required to keep the motion of the ball in a circle. If you release the rope, the ball will travel in a linear path.
You can use vectors to describe the relative distance between two points: $$\vec d = \vec r_1 - \vec r_2$$
Similarly you can use the instantaneous velocities at a time to describe relative velocities. Suppose two particles had circular motions, with $\vec r_1(t) = r_1(\cos(\omega_1t) \hat x + \sin(\omega_1 t) \hat y)$ and $\vec r_2(t) = r_2(\cos(\omega_2t) \hat x + \sin(\omega_2 t) \hat y)$. This would describe circular motion. The velocities are:
$$\frac{\partial \vec r_1(t)}{\partial t} = -r_1\omega_1\sin(\omega_1t) \hat x + r_1\omega_1\cos(\omega_1 t) \hat y$$ for particle 1, and $$\frac{\partial \vec r_2(t)}{\partial t} = -r_2\omega_2\sin(\omega_2t) \hat x + r_2\omega_2\cos(\omega_2 t) \hat y$$ for particle 2. You can use vector subtraction to find the relative velocities at a given time $t$.